# Express Renders Pug File to Same URL?

Tags: javascript, api, express, pug, server-side-rendering

When I fill out my form and submit my data, it renders my `order.pug` file on the browser, but my `URL` is still showing just `localhost:3000` instead of `localhost:3000/order`?

My pug file is in a `views` folder and my express.js file is just on the main directory for my project

Here is my express file

```
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.get("/orderPug", (req, res) => {
  res.render("orderPug");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
```

Then my post request to accept my data, then render my `order.pug` file

```
app.post("/create", async (req, res) => {
 //API Authentication code is here

  
  res.render("order")
});
```

My Pug File looks like this, so if I just navigate to `localhost:3000/order` it will show the value hard coded like below.

```
  h1 Total: $#{totalCost}
```

But after I submit my form data it ends up looking like this, except the `URL` is still on `localhost:3000`

```
  Total: $100.00
```

So when I submit my form, it shows the page has updated to `order.pug` yet the `URL` still just shows `localhost:3000` and I don't think that makes sense for a confirmation page to show?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you submit a form with `POST /create`, the URL for the response page will be `localhost:3000/create`. If yours is `localhost:3000`, how do you submit the form? Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: I'm not submitting a form, I have a function using Javascript that gets the data and renders it onto my `order.pug` file. I am using `res.render('my pug file')` so that is why it doesn't create a new URL

Comment: If you are using Ajax or fetch, then yes, the page itself is not posted. The browser doesn't load a new page from the server. Your Javascript is calling `/order` in the background. The page isn't reloaded. Some parts of the page may be updated dynamically, if your Javascript code updates them.